# How to Pass variable to locator in locator.py file based on page object model design pattern

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-django

I have a locator.py file which has below locator xpath

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class gm_Inbox_Locator(object):

    gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment = (By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@aria-label,'Press enter to view the attachment and delete to remove it')]//div[contains(text(),'sprint1')]")
```

I want to make **'sprint1'** as variable and while leveraging this locator in test method. How can I achieve this, any solution is appreciated. Thanks

```
def verify_attachment_is_attached_in_compose_email(self):
        try:
            self.wait_visibility_of_element_located(*self.locator.gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment)            
            logging.info(f"Attachment is attached")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception Occurred : "+str(e))
```

I tried adding variable like this

gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment = (By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@aria-label,'Press enter to view the attachment and delete to remove it')]//div[contains(text(),Attachment)]")

and Attachment here is a variable but this is not working as im not sure how to pass variable into a method and from method into a locator file

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired behavior by replacing class property `gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment` with method with input argument like this:

```
class gm_Inbox_Locator(object):
    @staticmethod
    def gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment(attachment):
        return (By.XPATH, f"//div[contains(@aria-label,'Press enter to view the attachment and delete to remove it')]//div[contains(text(),'{attachment}')]")
```

So your usage will be:

```
self.wait_visibility_of_element_located(*self.locator.gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment("some_attachment"))
```

Other possible solution is to store kind of string template in variable and use `format` to dynamically fill it with string value like this:

```
class gm_Inbox_Locator(object):
    gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment = "//div[contains(@aria-label,'Press enter to view the attachment and delete to remove it')]//div[contains(text(),'{}')]"
```

and

```
self.wait_visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, self.locator.gm_Compose_email_attached_attachment.format("some_attachment"))
```